# How to reload div (using JavaScript) to update changes in graph without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using `Nivo/line` to create a graph in a webpage and on receiving data from server (using `react`).

I want to update the change on the graph without reloading the entire page.

The data is being compiled in a `JavaScript` file everytime new data arrives.

I've used the following code but this code prints out the content of the JavaScript file on the HTML page:

```
$('#root').load('url to the file');
```

Comment: You should load just the data instead of HTML (using XHR or fetch) and render it on the client. Without your actual code and not explaining what the server is returning, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should provide your code in order to get better help, but theoretically, in your `react` app you can define a `state` of data then make it be your graph input, and when your state data change your graph will  change without reloading full page.
For example:

```
<mygraph data={this.state.mydata} />
```

Here you can read about state, [read about state](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/understanding-the-fundamentals-of-state-in-react-79c711be677f)

I hope you get the idea and works for you